# Mongoose populate() return null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am getting null as response for my query after using populate method instead of object

This is my route handler

```js
router.get("/:id", (req, res, next) => {
  let id = req.params.id;
  Order
    .findById(id)
    .populate('product')
    .exec()
    .then(doc => res.status(200).json({
      ...doc._doc,
      requests: {
        method: "GET",
        desc: "All Orders",
        url: "http://localhost:3000/orders"
      }
    }))

})
```

This is my Schema

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

var orderSchema = {
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  product: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Product",
    required: true
  },
  quantity: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1
  }
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
```

This is an example response I get after using populate(). Before using populate I a got an OjectId which I checked exists in the database

```
{
  "quantity": 1947,
  "_id": "5e25af75362bb0538c37b587",
  "product": null,
  "__v": 0,
  "requests": {
    "method": "GET",
    "desc": "All Orders",
    "url": "http://localhost:3000/orders"
  }
}
```

Comment: Well it worked after deleting the collections and creating them again. I am not sure why this happens. I thing it's some internal error of mongoDb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#doc-not-found) behave like left join in SQL DB, meaning it returns null or empty array if there is no foreign document found.

And because maybe you have added this field later to the collection schema, so in previous documents that field was empty.

Comment: As far as i remember I never changed the Schema. But is there a way i can cross check it?

Comment: @AbhinavMani, mongoose/mongodb don't have validation for foreign IDs, so the proper way is to validate the foreign ID yourself before the insert(save). you can do so by creating a [hook(middleware)](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html).